# How to add additional function to tt template in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, t4

I have default generated .tt template without any edits and so default generated entities. I want to override toString() method for all my entities to build big string with all properties' names and values. It'll look like this:

```
toString(){ return nameof(prop1)=prop1?.toString() ?? string.Empty + ";" + nameof(prop2)=prop2...}
```

Where and what I need to add in template file?
P.S. You can offer better/another syntax if it will be the same result

Comment: _"I want to override `ToString()` method for all my entities to build big string with all properties' names and values."_ - don't do this. Instead why not use `[DebuggerDisplay]`? Also, see https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator

Comment: But it's not for debug. I need one string with all entity data in program

Comment: Why, though? [Remember to keep the SRP in mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), so types that do one thing should not also be doing _another thing_ - (and **EF Entity classes are not DTOs**), so why not use a proper serialization library (`Newtonsoft.Json`?) - and what if you had a `varbinary` column or other columns that can't be easily represented in a `String`?

Comment: Also, **exactly** which `.tt` T4 template are you using? Are you using EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: I use EF6. And I want to use this toString() with one purpose - to find entity by field name and data in the field that must input dynamically by user, the easiest way I found it use overrided toString() and use Contains() or regex. Other manipulation with founded entity I would do using properties directly

Comment: That is **not** the best way to implement in-memory searching of data/objects... there are _much better ways_ to do it - besides, that approach means you can't search a database quickly (as in, using SQL), instead the client will need to load the entire table into memory first - you need to re-think this whole thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I'll review the searching part of my app